# Facebook Integration Development and Testing

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am in the process of developing an application that integrates with Facebook using their Javascript SDK. I am discovering a really interesting problem:

How does one test the FB functions in Facebook without actually having to deploy the application???

I have a development environment where I am writing server- side code that receives information (using Ajax) that is acquired using the FB.getLoginStatus() function. Unfortunately, that function only actually appears to work when I put it into an actual deployed version of the application!

In other words, it looks like in order to test if my server- side handlers of Facebook information are working properly, I actually have to deploy my server- side code in order for the Javascript SDK functions to work properly!

This means, of course, that I cannot debug my server- side code (unless, of course, I want to set up a full- fledged debug environment *on my deployment machine*) and cannot run proper testing and debugging because a deployed version of the code is already being used by clients!

Can anyone suggest a way to do the testing I need to do in a separate, development environment, one that will allow the Javascript to work and enable me to actually work on my server- side code without having to deploy everything?

Someone please advise...

UPDATE: As Sahil requested, here is some code. It should be familiar...

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : XXXXXXXXXXXXX,
  status     : false,
  xfbml      : true
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status == 'connected') {
  alert('Logged in');
} else {

      alert('Need to Log In');
    }
  });
};
```

The code is in a static HTML file. There are no server- side calls. It is straight FB Javascript SDK code.

When I serve files on my development machine (it has Internet access) the alerts do not display. When I put it on my deployment machine, they do display.

Debugging in the development environment shows that the functions get called but the response is never received. In the deployment environment, however, the response is received, as shown by my debugger.

So: what is it in this code that I am doing "wrong" that would cause it not to work in a development environment???

Comment: You are doing something wrong. There's no need to deploy you can test every on local server, no matter you use javascript/php sdk

Comment: OK... How??? The Javascript SDK functions do nothing in my development environment, but work fine in the deployed environment. I make no code changes from one to the other (I copy files from development to deployment). So: what is it that makes the Javascript work? It looks like it has to be in the deploy environment...

Comment: I'm not sure, but it works on local server. `The Javascript SDK functions do nothing in my development environment`- show some code..